# Excel Cell Validation required

Tags: excel, validation

I am new to excel. Looking forward how can I achieve the below. I have excel with 2 columns:

```
RollNo    Status
1          Passed
2          Passed
2          Fail
3          OK
2          <Here if RollNo 2 is already having the Status=Fail, 
           I should not allow RollNo=2 value 
           in this row>
So there is a validation required in RollNo field
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not allowing"? Showing an error message? Putting other situation in that cell instead? Highlight some cell as a warning? ...?

Comment: In the event of consecutive entries, select column A, then go to validation. Add the following custom rule: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"Fail")=0`. Now try to type the '2' in `A6` again. It will validate as false and give the user a warning.

Comment: Thanks its working, but the issue is with copy/paste. If I copy "Fail" RollNo again, the validation passes. Apologies for poor formatting and wordings.